# HTML into a text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, text-files

I am trying to get this information into a text file using PHP.

All of the websites that I have looked at only really cover entering a first and a last name had having the information echoed.

I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion on how to do this? That would be very helpful.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" />
        Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
 <input type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $
form action="action.php" method="post" />
        Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $

<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Control">Control Systems Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Image">Image Processing Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Optimiz">Optimization Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Robust">Robust Control Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Signal">Signal Processing   Toolbox<br>
Please enter a comma separated list of toolboxes you would like to use for you$
<input type="text" name="textquestion" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What do you mean "into a text file"? do you want that `action.php` will save the information in text file ?

Comment: Why do you "auto-close" your `<form>` tag? Why you have duplicated code fragments?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward,

```
$file = "myfile.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_POST['tool'])) { 
   $fh = fopen($file, 'a'); 
   $text = $_POST['question']. ' ' .$_POST['tool']; 
   fwrite($fh,$text); // Write form data to the file
   fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
```

This would be put in your action.php file, and would write to a file in the same directory.

Also a caveat, you have input names that aren't unique, so you would want to add a third field to this. 'question' should be a unique name as you're using it when posting data.